# Wwise: play specific audio clip without specific event (for dialogue)

Tags: unity, wwise

Is it possible to play a specific audio object in Wwise without having a separate event for it? I'm implementing a dialogue system, and I have thousands of audio clips for dialogues, and making an event for each and every one would be extremely time consuming and error prone and impossible to maintain.

So either play an audio object from a bank directly or somehow giving the event an argument as to which object to play (I know that goes against the idea of events and the fact that the caller shouldn't know exactly what clip is going to be played).

I believe what I'm looking for is something akin to FMOD's audio tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Wwise External Source plugin, described relatively well [here](https://www.audiokinetic.com/library/2017.1.9_6501/?source=SDK&id=integrating__external__sources.html). The docs on this feature are not the best, but the general workflow I used went something like this:

1. Stored voice over files outside the Wwise project and Unity streaming assets folder (could be anywhere, I used a folder next to the Assets folder)
2. Create a new Voice audio object in Wwise and add an External Source to it (edit the audio object, click "Add Source" and select External Source)
3. Wrote a simple python script to generate a .wsources XML file that reads all the files in the voice files folder
4. Add the .wsources file to the external sources in Project Settings in Wwise
5. Post the event from Unity with path being whatever you used as "Destination" in the .wsources file, ie. it's *not* an absolute path